# Compute $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos \theta}{5+4\cos\theta}\,d\theta$ using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

This question was asked in my complex analysis quiz and I was unable to solve it there.

> Show that $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos (\theta)}{5+ 4\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta = -\frac{\pi}{3} $.

5 + 4 cos $\theta$ is zero iff $cos(\theta) $= -5/4. So, there are no poles of the equation $\frac{\cos (\theta) } { 5+ 4\cos (\theta)}$. So, I think that residue theorem can't be used here.

Can you please give a hint or two on how to solve this problem using complex analysis?

Comment: $5+4 \cos \theta=0$ is *not* the same as $\theta=-5/4.$ You dropped the function name $\cos$ when you tried to solve.

Comment: Hint: Substitute $z=e^{i\theta}$. What happens to the integration range?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373498/complex-integral-using-residues?rq=1

Comment: If you find $$4\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{(1-t^2)dt}{(9+t^2)(1+t^2)}$$ easier to deal with, then Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea here is to consider an integral of a complex valued function around the unit circle which will become your integral once you parametrize. Cauchy's theorems can then be applied to evaluate the complex integral. Consider
$$ \int_{C(0,1)} \frac{z}{2z^2+5z+2} \, dz $$
where $C(0,1)$ is the unit circle. Parametrizing we have
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{i\theta}}{2e^{2i\theta}+5e^{i\theta}+2} ie^{i\theta} \, d \theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{i\theta}}{2e^{i\theta}+5+2e^{-i\theta}} \, d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{i\theta}}{5+4\cos \theta} \, d\theta $$
and so what we need to find is the imaginary part of the complex integral. Factoring and applying Cauchy's integral formula gives
$$  \int_{C(0,1)} \frac{z}{2z^2+5z+2} \, dz = \int_{C(0,1)} \frac{z}{2(z+2)\left(z+\frac{1}{2} \right)} \, dz = 2\pi i \left. \frac{z}{2(z+2)} \right|_{z=-\frac{1}{2}} = -\frac{\pi i}{3} $$
since the only pole within the unit circle is a simple pole at $-\frac{1}{2}$. Equating imaginary parts gives the value $-\frac{\pi}{3}$ for your integral.